# Monthly variables to a 6 by 12 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Right now I have a query that is getting data for 12 month based on a while loop, with 6 variables for each month, and then throwing it into a temp table that is 72 x 2.

It looks like:

```
Type1  |   Value
Type1  |   Value
... 12 times
Type2  |   Value
Type2  |   Value
... 12 times
ETC.
```

What I want that to look like at the end of the day is:

```
  Type 1   |   Type 2  |   Type 3  |   Type 4  |   Type 5  |   Type 6  
   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |   Value   |   Value
```

However I need to make sure that all the types of value are from the same month.

If I pivot it only creates one row.. or maybe overwrites itself over and over again with the same values?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What pivot query did you use, specifically what aggregation method

Comment: "If I pivot it only creates one row" might be the result of missing the month column in your query...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Month column was missing as suggested in comment.